# Cannot Create a new Project using Bitnami Django Stack console

Tags: django, bitnami

I have installed bitnami django stack 1.8.7. I want to create a new project from the bitnani django console, but it does not work it does not recognize django-admin.py and the manage.py.

I followed this documentation https://bitnami.com/stack/django/djangostack.pdf

The bitnami django console does not recognize python and django commands

Can you help me please? What I m doing wrong??

Comment: That documentation is over two years old, and written for Django 1.4. Is there a reason you're not just installing Python and Django?

Comment: Yes, because I want to use an apache server

Comment: You can also install mod_wsgi with Apache separately. I read the Bitnami README, and it doesn't even tell you if it includes mod_wsgi, or which version. I honestly think you'd be better off taking the time to learn how to install separately, especially to learn what security concerns there may be. To learn more about mod_wsgi (and mod_wsgi express, which is a big help for developers): https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

That documentation is really old.

The link below explains how to create a new Django project using Bitnami Django stack (check `Native Installer` tab):
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Django_Stack#How_to_create_a_new_Django_project.3f

I hope it helps.

P.S.: I know you have found this documentation. However, it could be useful for other users. Regards.